# multiple awaits are running in parallel

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to learn async/await and promises and unable to make run multiple async functions in serial.

```
function firstFunction () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => console.log('first'), 2000)
    resolve()
  })
}

function secondFunction () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => console.log('second'), 1000)
    resolve()
  })
}

async function main() {
  await firstFunction()
  await secondFunction()
}

main()
```

Output I am getting is

```
second
first
```

Since there's an await for firstFunction(), I'd expect the promise of firstFunction() to finish before going to secondFunction().

Can someone point out why they ran in parallel and how to make them run one after the other? (ran in node v18.3.0)

Comment: `firstFunction` doesn't wait for the timeout to finish before it resolves. Same with `secondFunction` If this is your *real code*, then you need to resolve when the timeout triggers. But if that's *not* representative of your real code, you better supply a [mcve]

Comment: Both functions resolve immediately after starting the timeouts. Did you mean to resolve within the timeout callbacks?

Comment: Put your `resolve`s inside your `setTimeout`s

Comment: @DaveNewton I wanted the first function to execute before the second function. Tried resolving inside the timeout callback and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @VLAZ I am trying a function which calls an api first and then saves the response in a database. Since the database call happened first, I was trying to understand why. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your **resolve()** call inside **setTimeout()** function. Here is the fixed code:

```js
function firstFunction () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('first');
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function secondFunction () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('second');
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  })
}

async function main() {
  await firstFunction()
  await secondFunction()
}

main()
```